# Self .active menu item

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following script:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.MenuAutoActive = function() {

        var menus = $('ul li a');
        //menus.removeClass('active');

        var matches = menus.filter(function() {
            return document.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) >= 0;
        });

        matches.addClass('active');
    };
```

What id does:

- it loop through all ul > li list in search for 'a'
- check 'a' for 'href'
- if href = current URL it adds class'active' to it

The only problem I have with it it looks only in last bit of the href:

for example: Main Menu will be:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"></a></li>
    <li><a href="Services/index.html"></a></li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio/index.html"></a></li>
    <li><a href="Conact/index.html"></a></li>
</ul>
```

URL = http://www.website.com/Services/

In this case script WILL NOT mark the `<a href="Services/index.html"></a>` as the URL does not contains index.html.

How can I make look in last ( after last / ) and one before last bit( before last / ) of the URL?

Any help much appreciated!

Pete

Comment: Are you using relative paths on purpose? Would be very easy with absolute paths.

Comment: Basically, there will be categories(e.g courses categories) will 10's(50-60) subpages - with this script + <base href="www.website.com/" /> will be much much easier to update website with for example one extra subpage. Where if I have it all in one folder and without self active - I would have to do it manually - which would take hours.

Comment: Also, there will be two types of menus, one at the top(whit categories - main menu), plus left hand side menu with subpages in this current category. Scripts works fine with left hand side menu (as there are short paths without category URL ), where TOP menu will be same on every page on every category - and current script does not work with it - because its looking only on the last chunk of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
return document.location.href.indexOf(this.href) >= 0;
```

Note that this accesses the `href` *property*  of the DOM element. This will return the absolute URL.

So `this.href` will give you `http://www.website.com/index.html` and not only `index.html`.

Comment: So would I have to use full absolute path? Or <base> would take care of that?

Comment: It does work with <base href="www.website.com" />! This is the perfect solution! Thanks.

Comment: @Pete: Yes, if you don't use `base` then the URLs will be interpreted as relative and the path changes depending on which website you are. It should still work though I think. Anyway, you got it working, that's the most important thing :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
document.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) >0
```

by

```
document.location.toString().indexOf($(this).attr('href')) >0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bits=$(this).attr('href').split('/');
var thelastbit=bits.pop(); 
var thepenultimatebit=bits.pop(); // previous call removed the last bit
```

May be quicker if you don't put index.html in the link in the first place or remove it while interrogating

```
return document.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href').replace('index.html','')) >= 0;
```

Comment: I have to put index.html - for home page.